# Implementing a 'for loop' within user_data provisioner file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am currently using a `template_file` to provision `user_data` into an `aws_launch_configuration`, like so:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "launch_config" {
    ...
    user_data                     = "${data.template_file.init.rendered}"
}

data "template_file" "init" {
    template = "${file("router-init.sh.tpl")}"

    vars {
        hub_ip_addresses = "${join(",", aws_instance.gridHub.*.private_ip)}"
    }
}
```

I am feeding in a variable (i.e. hub_ip_addresses) into the `router-init.sh.tpl` file, and in this file I am making use of the argument like so:

```
`#!/bin/sh
...  
IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$hub_ip_addresses"
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    #do stuff with $element
done
```

Basically, I am splitting the string based on a delimiter, and then looping through each ip address in the array.

This bash script works fine when I run it on my local machine -- however, when terraform executes it, it throws a error:
`* data.template_file.init: data.template_file.init: failed to render : parse error at 13:25: expected expression but found invalid sequence "@"`

I'm supposing the '@' symbol is causing an issue. Is there a reason why this is so? Do I need to escape it with a '\' ?

EDIT: Not sure if related to this issue, but in the preceeding line in the bash script, `IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$hub_ip_addresses"`, the `<<<` seems to be causing everything else that follows to look as if they are inside a comment (i.e. greyed out as if it was within a quotation mark `'`).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` characters in your template by doubling them up or Terraform will attempt to interpolate them as the input variables to the template.

The [template docs cover this briefly](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html#inline-templates) although the example given is for inline templates rather than for all templates, including those that are loaded with the [`file()` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#file-path-).

So something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
...  
IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$hub_ip_addresses"
for element in "$${array[@]}"
do
    #do stuff with $$element
done
```